# Find USB Drive letter

Tags: batch-file

I need to get the drive letter of the usb pen drive.the command CHDIR >drive.txt gives me the drive letter L:.How do I read/get this info "L:" without quotes into a variable in my batch file

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get a USB drive letter from any drive.

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 

2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
echo %%i is a USB drive.
)
)
```

Comment: this is useful; but what if there is a (multi) card reader it will mention them too.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `chdir` outputs can also be used by the pseudo-variable `%CD%`. So you already have a variable with that information.

Otherwise you can use `for`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('chdir') do set "drive=%%x"
```

But I think `%CD%` is much easier :-)

**EDIT:** You said that with the quotes already. You won't have any quotes in the variable unless you want them in there.

As for the trailing backslash: You can use the following instead of `%CD%`:

```
%CD:~0,-1%
```

which will expand `%CD%` and remove the last character, which you know is the backslash.

Still, will only work if you're in the root directory of that drive. Otherwise you can also use

```
for %%x in (%cd%) do @set drive=%%~dx
```

Comment: %CD% is ok similar to chdir but I need to remove the backslash "\" the variable should only be "L:" without quotes

Answer (score 1):

Using, in your batch, something like:

```
set Drive=%cd:~0,2%
```

Would yeld a content of **L:** as you asked, if this is the current directory the script is in, at the point when you use it.  If you have some popd/pushd, cd, etc.. within the batch, take care when you use it. The rest is up to you

Providing how you would use it (a part of your batch maybe) would have help alot to receive a better answer.  We only can guess.  The reason, I think, for the couple of **for** loops in answers.  Might not be needed but we're guessing.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in (d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do vol %%a: 2>nul |find "NAME OF THE USB" >nul && 
set drv=%%a:
%drv%
```

This i what i use to find the letter on my USB

- Just change the "NAME OF THE USB" to the name of the USB

Answer (score 0):

Since `cd` will output something like:

```
c:\documents and settings\pax
```

you need to just grab the first field using `"\"` as the delimiter as follows:

```
for /f "delims=\" %d in ('cd') do set curdrv=%d
```

This will set the environment variable `curdrv` to `c:` for the aforementioned output.

Don't forget to use the double-% (%%d) variant if running inside a cmd file.