# create a folder on volume number

Tags: batch-file

I have a usb drive and need to create a folder on that drive based on the volume number. I tried this but get error as the syntax of command is incorrect.

```
@echo off

   for /F "skip=1 tokens=5" %%a in ('vol %~D0') do set Serial=%%a
if %Serial% equ 890-8132 do (
 mkdir \usb transfer\"

)
```

Comment: Are you running this from the flash drive?

Comment: no I am trying it run from windows..

Comment: `IF` doesn't use `DO` so remove that. This will only work from the location the script is running from. Take the code MC ND gave you earlier and use the drive letter from it in place of `%~D0`

Answer (score 0):

The question has not yet been closed, so perhaps there is not enough detailed answer for the questioner. The code from MC ND is not visible here either. Using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788554/find-usb-drive-letter), and fixing other bugs (such as missing quotes and so on,we might get:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set usbs=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (
    if %%l equ 2 (
      echo %%i is a USB drive.
      set /a usbs += 1
      set usb[!usbs!]=%%i
      mkdir "%%i\usb transfer\"
    )
)
echo %usbs% USB Drives found
exit /b
```

This makes a folder on any/all inserted USB drives.