# Batch file commands and using command prompt to accomplish this

Tags: android, windows, batch-file

Couple of questions, with all of them regarding batch code.

So my first question is that if I have a batch file, and it has commands in it, how would I do something like this in command prompt?

```
cd C:\User\username\Desktop\folder\
```

And in folder, there is a file called `CMDTEST.bat`. With this, I would want to use commands from there. In this file, it starts off by giving me a few choices. There are three, which are selected by typing `i`, for input, `o`, for output, a for ADB connection, and `q` for quit. My question is, how would I do something like this?

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\CMDTEST.bat -i
```

The goal of typing something like this, is it would directly go to the `CMDTEST.bat` file, and then execute the choice if 'i' was put in. Similarly, there would something for 'o', something for 'a', and something for 'q'. How would I go about accomplishing this?

My second question is how do I get the directory of a connected USB device? In my case, I have to get the directory of a connected tablet, which has files on it. I need to make all this run pretty quickly, so I need the directories with a simple command, like if I did the same thing as the above code block, but something like:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\CMDTEST.bat -d
```

That would list all the usb devices connected, with their name as shown in Windows Explorer, and the path used to access the device. All of the devices would be android tablets, so theres no need for a root scheme or  anything to that extent.

The third and final question I have is how would I check in an if statement, whether things were printed in a cmd Android ADB statement where I write:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\platform-tools(this is where the Android SDK is stored)
```

and then I would write

```
adb devices
```

which would print all available devices connected(all android devices). How would I check if things are printed from that, and if they ARE NOT, then continue to search for them in a loop, until at least one device is found, then when it is found, break out of the loop?

Comment: It's not clear if you understand the difference between MS-DOS(Windows) `.bat` files and `bash` shell scripts. when you use path notation like `c:\path\to\dir` we understand that  you are using the Windows environment. Because you want to process arguments (`-i`, etc), you use `%1%` (or is it %%1%%`) etc for the positional parameters. BUT as is this Q is too hard to understand what your goal is. You should really trim it down to your first problem, and make clear what your goal is. Hard to say where to go from here. Good luck.

Comment: So can someone just answer the first question? that being, I want to be able to simply use one line, and write

CMD.bat -i

and that would run the input code?

Comment: Like shellter said, you'd use an `if` statement based on the value of `%1`. Also, bash is a completely different language and not what you want at all.

Answer (score 2):

**First question:**

> So my first question is that if I have a batch file, and it has commands in it, how would I do something like this in command prompt?
>
> ```
> cd C:\User\username\Desktop\folder\
> ```

Use `cd /d` to change current drive as well as current directory.  Combine that with the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable to dynamically get to the currently logged in user's folder.  You should end up with something like this:

```
cd /d %userprofile%\desktop
```

**Second question:**

> My question is, how would I do something like this?
>
> ```
> C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\CMDTEST.bat -i
> ```
>
> The goal of typing something like this, is it would directly go to the CMDTEST.bat file, and then execute the choice if 'i' was put in. Similarly, there would something for 'o', something for 'a', and something for 'q'. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Batch scripts recognize parameters as `%1`, `%2`, and so on.  You could do something like this in your script:

```
if %1==a (
   goto optionA
) else if %1 ==o (
   goto optionO
) else if %1 ==q (
   goto optionQ
) else (       
   goto end
)
:optionA
{do option A suff}
:optionO
{do option O suff}
:optionQ
{do option Q suff}
:end
echo No valid option was provided
```

**<del>Second Second question:</del>
Next Question:**

> My <del>second</del> [next] question is how do I get the directory of a connected USB device?

I don't have the answer for you, but you might look at this other question on SO: [Find USB Drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788554/find-usb-drive-letter)

**<del>Third and</del> Final question:**

> The <del>third and</del> final question I have is how would I check in an `if` statement, whether things were printed in a cmd Android `ADB` statement.  How would I check if things are printed from that, and if they ARE NOT, then continue to search for them in a loop, until at least one device is found, then when it is found, break out of the loop?

I'm not familiar with the function of `abd devices` and what or how it outputs.  However, assuming it outputs to the screen you could probably pipe (`|`) the output to a `FIND` command or something to make your determination.  As stated in the comments, you might have better luck trimming this out and asking it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wes! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SonGoku : meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242 . Good luck to all.