# how to find usb drive letter and set path for new folders and files is that, in batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 

2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
echo %%i is a USB drive.
)
)
```

I used above commands in batch file and able to get usb drive letter from-
[Find USB Drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788554/find-usb-drive-letter)

but please someone help me, how to use that letter in same batch file to create folders and files in the same drive, and it should work even if use as path for any specific command

Comment: Note that using `drivetype 2` doesn't find all usb drives. I have a removable USB drive that reports itself as `drivetype 3` (Local hard disk)

Answer (score 1):

With the above script, the output should be something like `X: is a USB drive`.

So with that one knows that in `%%i` `X:` is stored. Knowing this, one can set the letter to a variable like this: `set "driveLetter=%%~i"` for later use. This could be creating a directory for example:

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 

2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
echo %%i is a USB drive.
set "driveLetter=%%~i"
)
)
md "%driveLetter%\myFolder"
```