# USB drive Letter finder

Tags: loops, batch-file

I have this script that checks for a certain USB and then opens a file on it. However, now I need it to check only for the drive letter of the USB  inserted so. However I don't really know how to do that and searches online returned nothing that could help me. 
This is the script I have right now:

```
@echo off
:loop
if exist D:\ (goto Load) else (goto loop)
:Load

D:
start Loader1.exe
goto Finish

:Finish 
exit
```

Comment: Your code does not check for a certain USB, it checks only for a mounted drive assigned to `D:`. I'm not sure if you're aware, but Microsoft disabled auto-running removable disks due to security concerns. For this reason, I would suggest that you build some security into your script, so that it will only run on the specific device, not any. The idea of this site is to seek help with a specific issue with your code. Your code however doesn't exhibit an issue, so your requesting code, which is off topic here. Please search and write some code, for us to assist you with, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this that you are looking?

---

This will take over the task only on the Removable Disk and will be given the associated logical name of each for check if your file **Loader1.exe** is there for take next action.

> - [See this link: How To List Drive Letters](https://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/batch_files/how_to_list_drive_letters.htm):

- Value Meaning for **`drivetype`** in **`WMIC logicaldisk`**

  **`0 Unknown`**

  **`1 No root directory`**

  **`2 Removable disk`**

  **`3 Local disk`**

  **`4 Network drive`**

  **`5 Compact disk`**

  **`6 RAM disk`**

  ---

> - **`wmic logicaldisk get caption,drivetype|find "2"`**
>
>   ---

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

```bat
This Result Removable disk : 
D:       2
E:       2
F:       2
G:       2
```

> - **Caption** = **D:**
> - **DriveType** = **Removable disk** == **2**

---

After, and make sure the **`Loader1.exe`** file exist to start/run your command:

> **`Driver:\Loader1.exe`**

The last part, time out (1 minute) to perform the next loop:

> **`timeout 60 >nul && goto :loop`**

---

```bat
@echo off

:loop
for /f %%i in ('"wmic logicaldisk get caption,drivetype|find "2""')do if exist "%%~i\Loader1.exe" (
    cd /d %%~i\ & start .\Loader1.exe && goto :Finish )

timeout 60 >nul & goto :loop)

:Finish
```

- **`::  Or ::`**

---

```bat
@echo off

set "_cd=%cd%" && title <nul

:loop

for /f %%i in ('"wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get name|find /v "Name""
')do if exist "%%~i\Loader1.exe" cd /d %%~i\ & start .\Loader1.exe & cd /d "%_cd%" & exit /b

timeout 60 >nul & goto :loop
```

Comment: Whilst many USB storage devices do show as removable, _(DriveType 2)_, this is certainly not reliable.

Comment: For sure, but, only one have the file Loader1.exe!?

Comment: Well, I suppose we could assume that, but if the particular USB storage device doesn't identify itself as a removable drive, _(DriveType 2)_, and as we have no control over that, it will not find the device to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the USB drive letter from any drive:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do ( 
  if %%l equ 2 ( echo %%i is a USB drive. ) 
)
```

Answer is not a duplicate of @scientist_7 I got it from [Find USB Drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788554/find-usb-drive-letter).

Comment: Whilst many USB storage devices do show as removable, _(DriveType 2)_, this is certainly not reliable.